# Using nested for loop in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a set of graphs to compare the simulation results with the experimental data. The simulation files are in ordered arrangement on 7X7X7 for various parameters. I need to plot all of those files using a nested for loop for each iXjXk file. The files are named thus : fibrilAll_i_j_k.dat

I have already tried some alternatives like using multiple for loop in the same line. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
set terminal eps size 1200,800
set output "all.eps"
set title "{/*2 Alternative rates}"
set ylabel "{/*2 fibril mass fraction}" offset 1.5,0,0
set xlabel "{/*2 Time(h)}"
set key left top
plot 'experiment.txt' using 1:6 ps 2 pt 5 title "EXP",\
for [i=1:7] for [j=1:7] for [k=1:7] 'fibrilAll'._i_j_k.'.dat' using 1:2 with lines title 'i,j,k'
replot
```

I get the following error message:

internal error : STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable

Answer (score 0):

I see a few possible problems.

1) I take it you do not want to plot the same file `fibrilAll_i_j_k.dat` 343 times. 
If the data files are named e.g. `fibrilAll_1_5_3.dat` then you can construct that name by saying `plot ... sprintf("fibrilAll_%d_%d_%d.dat",i,j,k)`

2) Probably you want something similar for the titles

3) The `replot` does not accomplish anything.  Did you leave out something?

Comment: I tried the following and it worked       ```set terminal png size 1200,800 
    set output "all.png"  
    set title "{/*2 Alternative rates}"  
    set ylabel "{/*2 fibril mass fraction}" offset 1.5,0,0  
    set xlabel "{/*2 Time(h)}" 
    set key left top  
    plot 'experiment.txt' using 1:6 ps 2 pt 5 title "EXP"  
    do for [i=1:7]{  
     do for [j=1:7]{  
      do for[k=1:7]{  
      filename = sprintf("%s_%d_%d_%d.%s",'fibrilAll',i,j,k,'dat')  
       plot filename using 1:2 with lines title "1",\  
       }  
      }  
    }```

Comment: Ah.  It was not clear in the original question that you wanted to plot each file separately rather than plotting all of the files in a single figure.